# Get empty array when using pipeline in MongoDB lookup aggregation

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have 2 collections as below

```
collectionA.insertOne({
    cart: [
        { product_id: ObjectId('xxx'), quantity: 10 }
    ]
})
collectionB.insertMany([
    { _id: ObjectId('xxx'), name: '', price: 1 },
    { _id: ObjectId('xyz'), name: '', price: 1 },
])
```

When I trying $lookup with foreign/localField it's OK

```
{
  from: 'collectionB',
  localField: 'cart.product_id',
  foreignField: '_id',
  as: 'product_detail'
}
```

But I want switch to using pipeline as below:

```
{
  from: 'collectionB',
  let: {pid: '$cart.product_id'},
  pipeline: [
    {
    $match: {
        $expr: {
          $eq: ['$_id', '$$pid']
        }
    }
  }],
  as: 'product_detail'
}
```

Then I received an empty array in product_detail field.
How can I make it as my expectation?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$cart.product_id` you are getting an array with `_id` values, then into `$eq` you are comparing an ObjectId and an array.

As [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) is used to know if a value is into an array you have to use `$in` instead of `$eq` to get values like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/m_AWys9FAtT).

Result `$lookup` is like this:

```
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "collectionB",
    let: {pid: "$cart.product_id"},
    pipeline: [
      {
        $match: {
          $expr: {
            $in: [ //<--- here use $in
              "$_id",
              "$$pid"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    as: "product_detail"
  }
}
```